# Displaying only one field on form in combobox when editing ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am a django newbie so please forgive me the basic question.
I have a class in my model that has a ForeignKey. I am using django.views.generic.UpdateView for editing the fields. For the ForeignKey a combobox is displayed which is exactly what I want but all the fields of the referenced table appear in the combobox. I want to display only 2 in the combobox, for example: "field1 [field2]".
How can I control this behaviour?

Thanks,
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is to define the `__str__` function for my model class.

```
class Systm(ParentModel):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s [%s]" % (self.name, self.type)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because:

1. By default `ForeignKey` (which is a model field) will default to `ModelChoiceField` (form field).
2. By default `ModelChoiceField`'s `queryset` is *all* model objects.

If you want to change this behavior and give only few selected model objects for user to choose in your `ModelChoiceField`, you will have to override this field with `queryset` on your own. For example:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel

    your_foreignkey_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=YourOtherModel.objects.filter(some_criteria))
```

Then you can specify `form_class = YourForm` in `UpdateView`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Only I had to define the __str__ function in my model class.